# Why does converting text to numbers so much slower in tables?

Tags: excel

When converting 5500 cells with text to numbers I realised that it feels like it takes almost 1-2 minutes when they are in a table, but when I converted the table back to a range the conversion only took a second.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? Should I avoid tables when working with this amount of cells?

Comment: You have to be more specific about the process and the conditions under you’re performing this task

Comment: I believe it is down to Excel recalculating the whole sheet after converting each cell. A couple of options are to turn calculations off, or use the Text to Columns data tool (this will do the conversion and then calculate once)